# Inverse line graph year count matplotlib pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a lineplot of the count of three different groups i.e. desktop, mobile & tablet with the x axis having the years of 2014, 2015 and 2016 but I am getting the error

my code is currently:

```
#year-by-year change
desktop14 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201401) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201453) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "DESKTOP"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
desktop15 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201501) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201553) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "DESKTOP"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
desktop16 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201601) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201653) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "DESKTOP"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
mobile14 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201401) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201453) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "MOBILE"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
mobile15 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201501) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201553) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "MOBILE"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
mobile16 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201601) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201653) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "MOBILE"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
tablet14 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201401) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201453) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "TABLET"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
tablet15 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201501) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201553) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "TABLET"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]
tablet16 = od.loc[(od.Account_Year_Week >= 201601) & (od.Account_Year_Week <= 201653) & (od.online_device_type_detail == "TABLET"), "Gross_Demand_Pre_Credit"]

devicedata = [["Desktop", desktop14.count(), desktop15.count(), desktop16.count()], ["Mobile", mobile14.count(), mobile15.count(), mobile16.count()], ["Tablet", tablet14.count(), tablet15.count(), tablet16.count()]]
df = pd.DataFrame(devicedata, columns=["Device", "2014", "2015", "2016"]).set_index("Device")


plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to make each of the lines the Device types and the x axis showing the change in year. How do I do this - (essentially reversing the axis).

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `devicedata` is a list of lists, not a data frame. Lists don’t have a `plot` method. Data frames do. Convert it.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks I have done this, now how do i reverse the axes to make the lines the devices and the x axis the change of year? - Post updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
df.transpose().plot()
```

Result will be something like this:

[image]